# How to get Highcharts xAxis co-ordinate?

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to render a custom axis over the existing Highcharts

```
chart.renderer.rect(0, chart.chartHeight - BAR_XAXIS_PADDING, 420, 5)
.attr({
    fill : "black"
    //fill: "url('#hatching2d63c14a-4bcf-4b6c-9511-891d8abca5c4')"
}).add(axisGroup);
```

where the 0, BAR_XAXIS_PADDING is a hardcoded value. Is there a way to get the existing axis co-ordinate so that i can bind the custom axis to it?

Comment: What do you mean by `axis co-ordinate`?

Comment: The co-ordiniate of the of the actual x-axis line , (i.e) (x,y) of starting and ending points of the axis line

Comment: Use [`Axis.toPixels()`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.toPixels). To get min and max from the Axis, use [`Axis.getExtremes()`](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.getExtremes).

Comment: How do i use them to get axis co-ordinate? Could you help me with an example? I am trying to replace the existing axis line with my style of axis and would require the co-ordinates to draw renderer.rect() for axis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get extremes from

```
 var ex = chart.yAxis[0].getExtremes();
```

Then get y-coordinates for the axis:

```
var yBottom = chart.yAxis[0].toPixels(ex.min);
var yTop = chart.yAxis[0].toPixels(ex.max);
```

Now render rect:

```
chart.renderer.rect(chart.plotLeft, yTop, width, yBottom - yTop).add();
```

Comment: Thanks@Pawel ! Additionally, If the chart is inverted, how would we derive the co-ordinates?